# Error opening socket SSL

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization, ssl, acquia-dev-desktop

I am working with a Drupal 7 site locally that we have setup with OAuth2. Logging in works fine on our staging server, our QA server, and another guy's MacBook Pro.

On mine, however, I see an error that is thrown by the OAuth2 Client module in its `getToken()` function.

> Failed to get an access token of grant_type authorization_code. Error: Error opening socket ssl://staging.api.MYSITE.com:443

My system is using PHP 5.6. I am on a Mac running 10.10.

Any thoughts?